# In Vim, how to I set an autocommand to be run after a plugin has loaded?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

One of the Vim Plugins I use has a bug, causing it to set `:syntax spell notoplevel`. The bug is easily mitigated if I run the command `:syntax spell toplevel` after opening a file. However, I'm lazy and I'd like to put the fix in my `init.vim / .vimrc` file, so that it's run automatically.

How can I ensure that my fix is executed after the buggy plugin code, so that my setting is not overridden by the plugin?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a file in `~/.vim/after/plugin/` such as `~/.vim/after/plugin/fix-spell.vim` containing the command you'd run without the colon:

```
syntax spell toplevel
```

The files in `~/.vim/after/plugin` are sourced after your plugins have loaded, thus providing a convenient hook to change settings that might have been set by a plugin.

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else using NeoVim the default location of the `after/` directory is: `~/.config/nvim/after/`.

Comment: @andypea, thanks, to be specific, the default location is: `~/.config/nvim/after/plugin`.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can set it as an autocommand. There are a whole slew of events you can tie autocommands to (`:help events` for all of them). VimEnter is an event that fires after plugins are loaded, so you could set your command to run then with a line like this right in your vimrc:

```
autocmd VimEnter * syntax spell toplevel
```

That's what I am using to apply a plugin theme that is not available until after plugins load.